# How to delay on hover effect in react with css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, styles

I would like to create some sort of animation on hover for my gallery with using react hooks, but so far I am not successful.

**Goal explanation:**

I would like to achieve, that when I hover with mouse on image that has overlay on - it will first show text under the image, and after some time the text will disappear and image will delete the overlay - basically it will light up.

**What I did so far:**

I created some overlay on image which disappears on hover with help of CSS.

```
       <Col
          xs={6}
          className="img-wrap"
          onClick={() => setSelectedData(post)}
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        >
          <img src={post.image} alt="random" />
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="text">{post.name}</div>
          </div>
          {hover && selectedData === post && <h1>HOVER </h1>}
        </Col>
```

And the CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 210px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: black;
}

.img-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

This works fine, but the hover effects is triggered immediately instead of some time as I wish and the text is not shown on hover but `onClick`.

I think the best is to use setTime() function, but I am not sure how to connect it with css.'

Here is my sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-poitras-5y3b1?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the onClick, placed the setSelectedData in the onMouseEnter, added a setTimeout in there, and put your setHover in the timeout. I don't particularly like using setTimeouts, but this was a quick way to do what you were looking for.

```
<Col
    xs={6}
    className="img-wrap"
    onMouseEnter={() => {
       setSelectedData(post);
       setTimeout(() => {
           setHover(true);
       }, 1000);
    }}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
 >
```

In the css we need to lose the :hover psuedo selector, and add a class:

```
.img-wrap .overlay.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Then on the overlay we need to make the fade class conditional:

```
<div className={"overlay" + (hover && post === selectedData ? " fade" : "")}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-mayer-0si2d?file=/src/App.js:506-731

Comment: Thanks @wrxsti, that's very close. I just need it to work on each image individually. So -> hover on image n. 3 - show HOVER text, after 3s delete black overlay  -> when you leave the image - the overlay without HOVER text is gone and when you hover on other image, same thing happens.

Comment: @Eliot Updated the code, think we're pretty close here.

Answer (score 0):

Or by animating the css opacity property with a delay then there's no need for the timeout.

```
.img-wrap .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear 1s; // where 1s is your delay
}

img-wrap:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s linear 1s; // where 1s is your delay
}
```

More info about transition properties here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I agree CSS would be the preferred solution, but he asked specifically about using hooks, so thats why I answered with the timeout.